# Build and execute C program on the backend in a controlled environment?

Tags: linux, docker, gcc, backend

In a Web application, I would like to build C code and return the build errors or the stdout/stderr of that program.

My current solution is to call the following from my Laravel backend:

```
timeout 2 docker run --rm -v `pwd`/code.c:/tmp/ frolvlad/alpine-gcc gcc --static /tmp/code.c 
timeout 2 docker run --rm -v `pwd`/a.out:/tmp/ frolvlad/alpine-gcc ./a.out
```

Unfortunately, I have no real control over the timeout and the memory use.

How do websites such as https://rextester.com/l/cpp_online_compiler_gcc solve this kind of problem?

Comment: You can just have a wrapper script in the docker container that sets your desired CPU and memory limits with `ulimit`

Comment: @thatotherguy looks good!